# Jasmine : Angular, 'else path not taken', yet both test cases pass?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

My test coverage shows that the else path  is not taken, yet both of these test functions corresponding to the component method pass.

component method :

```
 radioSelect(event : MatRadioChange){

  let radioSelect=event.value;
  this.schedulerForm.reset();
    if (radioSelect == 'dayReport'){
      this.dayReport = true;
      this.rangeReport = false;
      this.schedulerForm.get('schedulerCategory').setValue('dayReport');
    }else if(radioSelect == 'rangeReport'){
      this.dayReport = false;
      this.rangeReport = true;
      this.schedulerForm.get('schedulerCategory').setValue('rangeReport');

    }
  }
```

tests

```
  it('should call radioSelect on change radio-button',() => {
    let event = {value:"rangeReport"}
    let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-radio-group'));
    de.triggerEventHandler('change', event);

    expect(component.dayReport).toBe(false);
    expect(component.rangeReport).toBe(true);
    expect(component.schedulerForm.controls['schedulerCategory'].value).toBe('rangeReport')

  });

  it('should call radioSelect on change radio-button',() => {
    let event = {value:"dayReport"}
    let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-radio-group'));
    de.triggerEventHandler('change', event);

    expect(component.dayReport).toBe(true);
    expect(component.rangeReport).toBe(false);
    expect(component.schedulerForm.controls['schedulerCategory'].value).toBe('dayReport')

  });
```

Thank you for your insight I've been stumping my head on this one,
SC

Comment: Have you tried setting sourceMap: true in your "test" configuration of angular.json and if it still does not work then try writing /* istanbul ignore else */, this is an ongoing issue in github ,
https://github.com/istanbuljs/babel-plugin-istanbul/issues/186

Comment: a good practice is to always use else with if.